# Swift 3 - Line is getting thicker in MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am using `MKMapView` and `PolyLine` concept to draw a line.But when the line is drawn line is getting thicker when it goes ahead.I want a single line throughout the route.

My code:-

```
 func assigArray() {
    if self.lat.count == self.lon.count {
        for i in 0 ..< self.lat.count {
            let destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.lat[i], self.lon[i])
            coordinateArray.append(destination)
        }
        self.mapp()
    }

}
func mapp() {
    let coords2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat.last!, longitude: lon.last!)
    let testline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinateArray, count: coordinateArray.count)
    //Add `MKPolyLine` as an overlay.
    map.add(testline)

    map.delegate = self

    map.centerCoordinate = coords2
    map.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coords2, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
}
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    renderer.lineWidth = 2.0
    return renderer
}
```

[image: line is getting thicker]

Comment: Did you override `mapView(_:rendererForOverlay)`? This may affecft the way that it's displayed.

Comment: @Stephen yes i did

Comment: Can you share that code here as well?

Comment: @Stephen check my updated question

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code here. I used https://www.raywenderlich.com/166182/mapkit-tutorial-overlay-views to build a similar test app and updated with your code from `mapp()` and `mapView(_:rendererForOverlay)`, but was unable to see an issue. I also scrambled the points to rule out a data issue. Have you tried with a different set of points (some hard-coded version of `coordinateArray`?